# How to find a specific sequence within the decimals of PI?

Tags: algorithm, math, pi

I want to find a specific sequence of digits in the decimals of PI and that involves first computing PI to (quite possibly) infinity. The problem is that I don't know how to make a variable store that many digits or how to just use the newly computed digit so I can compare it to my sequence.

So how can I calculate PI and keep only the last decimal as an integer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long is the sequence of digits?

Comment: [You want to compute Pi to the last digit?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RN5aQSN7qo8)

Comment: If this is an exercise in arbitrary-precision arithmetic, carry on. If finding the digits is the actual task, the work has already been done: [search in the first `2 * 10^9` digits here](http://www.subidiom.com/pi/), or [download the first `5 * 10^12` digits here](http://www.numberworld.org/digits/Pi/#Download).

Comment: I am trying to find a 29 digit long sequence, so that is highly unlikely to occur within the first few decimals, that's why I'm looking for a way to find a crapload of them to search through.
@AahashM: Thanks, your comment is a very good start point, albeit not in a programming way. If you would submit it as an answer I would gladly choose it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of problem can be solved very elegantly using lazy evaluation, like the one found in Haskell. Or using generators in Python, producing at most one number of Pi at a time, and checking against the corresponding position in target value that's being searched.

The advantage of either approach is that you don't have to generate a (potentially) infinite sequence of numbers, only generate as much as needed until you find what you're looking for. Of course, if the specific sequence *really* doesn't appear in the number Pi the algorithm will iterate forever, but at least the computer executing the program won't run out of memory.

Alternatively: you could use the [BBP Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BBPFormula.html), or a similar algorithm which allows the extraction of a specific digit in Pi.

Comment: This only works if you have a method `f(n)` that returns the `n`th digit of PI. Do you?

Comment: @IVlad for the first option: no, you can lazily calculate "all digits" but only look at one in particular, before advancing to the next one. For the second option: yes, this implies calculating the nth digit, but as mentioned above, such an algorithm exists.

Comment: Digit extraction algorithms like BBP are indeed the way to go I think, but I find your first two paragraphs confusing and not really relevant. The last sentence is all the OP needs I think, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterative algorithm for calculating Pi, for example, the [Gauss–Legendre algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm).

To implement it, you will need a library that does arbitrary-precision arithmetic; one such library is [GMP](http://gmplib.org).

Apparently, someone has done most of the work for you: http://gmplib.org/pi-with-gmp.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation in Python of a streaming algorithm described by Jeremy Gibbons in [Unbounded Spigot Algorithms for the Digits of Pi](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf) (2004), Chaper 6:

```py
def generate_digits_of_pi():
    q = 1
    r = 180
    t = 60
    i = 2
    while True:
        digit = ((i * 27 - 12) * q + r * 5) // (t * 5)
        yield digit
        u = i * 3
        u = (u + 1) * 3 * (u + 2)
        r = u * 10 * (q * (i * 5 - 2) + r - t * digit)
        q *= 10 * i * (i * 2 - 1)
        t *= u
        i += 1

# Demo
iter = generate_digits_of_pi()

from time import sleep
import sys

for i in range(1000):
    print (next(iter), end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.05)
```